# Check if id in string and get value if so

Tags: java, regex, match

I am trying to get a regex to match, then get the value with it. For example, I want to check for 1234 as an id and if present, get the status (which is 0 in this case). Basically its id:status. Here is what I am trying:

```
String topicStatus = "1234:0,567:1,89:2";
String someId = "1234";
String regex = "\\b"+someId+":[0-2]\\b";
if (topicStatus.matches(regex)) {
    //How to get status?
}
```

Not only do I not know how to get the status without splitting and looping through, I don't know why it doesn't match the regex.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class

```
String topicStatus = "1234:0,567:1,89:2";
String someId = "1234";
String regex = "\\b"+someId+":[0-2]\\b";

Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(regex);

Matcher m = MY_PATTERN.matcher(topicStatus);
while (m.find()) {
    String s = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

The key here is to surround the position you want `[0-2]` in parenthesis which means it will be saved as the first group. You then access it through `group(1)`

Answer (score 0):

I made some assumptions that your pairs we're always comma separate and then delimited by a colon.  Using that I just used `split`.

```
String[] idsToCheck = topicStatus.split(",");
        for(String idPair : idsToCheck)
        {
            String[] idPairArray = idPair.split(":");
            if(idPairArray[0].equals(someId))
            {
                System.out.println("id    : " + idPairArray[0]);
                System.out.println("status: " + idPairArray[1]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could we not use regex for this? I don't want to have to do this loop every time. Certain parts of my script are looping through values that need to do this check.

Comment: I'm certain there is a way, just showing an alternate solution, albeit more brute force-ish.